# Filter rows with a time value that falls within several ranges

Tags: r

I wonder if someone could help me out with this one.

A friend of mine is dealing with ecological data that needs to be filtered when a time value falls into several ranges. Let's say we have a data frame with 3 columns:

| ID | TIME | SPECIES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 22:45:43 | sp1 |
| 02 | 22:46:22 | sp2 |
| 03 | 23:21:11 | sp3 |
| 04 | 23:32:31 | sp1 |
| 05 | 00:11:37 | sp2 |
| 06 | 01:48:56 | sp4 |
| 07 | 02:36:22 | sp1 |

We want to select only those rows which time value is within several time ranges specified in another data frame:

| ID | START TIME | END TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 22:00:00 | 23:00:00 |
| 02 | 00:00:00 | 01:00:00 |

In the above example, this will result in rows ID 1,2 and 5.

Is there a way to do this without manually specifying the ranges one by one?

Many thanks beforehand!
Rob

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fuzzy_inner_join` to get the rows within the range. We convert the time values to POSIXct type so that we can compare the times.

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

df1 %>%
  mutate(TIME = as.POSIXct(TIME, format = '%T', tz = 'UTC')) %>%
  fuzzy_inner_join(df2 %>%
  mutate(across(c(START.TIME, END.TIME), 
          as.POSIXct, format = '%T', tz = 'UTC')), 
  by = c('TIME' = 'START.TIME', 'TIME' = 'END.TIME'), 
  match_fun = c(`>=`, `<=`)) %>%
  select(ID = ID.x, everything(), -ID.y) %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('TIME'), format, '%T'))

#  ID     TIME SPECIES START.TIME END.TIME
#1  1 22:45:43     sp1   22:00:00 23:00:00
#2  2 22:46:22     sp2   22:00:00 23:00:00
#3  5 00:11:37     sp2   00:00:00 01:00:00
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:7, TIME = c("22:45:43", "22:46:22", "23:21:11", 
"23:32:31", "00:11:37", "01:48:56", "02:36:22"), SPECIES = c("sp1", 
"sp2", "sp3", "sp1", "sp2", "sp4", "sp1")), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, START.TIME = c("22:00:00", "00:00:00"
), END.TIME = c("23:00:00", "01:00:00")), row.names = c(NA, -2L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

This can solved using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)'s `%inrange%` operator:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[as.ITime(TIME) %inrange% lapply(setDT(df2)[, -1], as.ITime)]
```

> ```
>    ID     TIME SPECIES
> 1:  1 22:45:43     sp1
> 2:  2 22:46:22     sp2
> 3:  5 00:11:37     sp2
> ```

Note that timestamps are coerced by `as.ITime()` to [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)'s integer time-of-day class.

#### Data

```
df1 <- readr::read_table(
"ID  TIME        SPECIES
01  22:45:43    sp1
02  22:46:22    sp2
03  23:21:11    sp3
04  23:32:31    sp1
05  00:11:37    sp2
06  01:48:56    sp4
07  02:36:22    sp1")
df2 <- readr::read_table(
"ID START TIME  END TIME
01  22:00:00    23:00:00
02  00:00:00    01:00:00")
```